# Existe algum risco em não validar o nome de uma função usada no JSONP?

Tags: php, segurança, jsonp

Geralmente, quando se disponibiliza um serviço `JSONP` uma das coisas a ser passada por parâmetro é o nome do callback que será utilizado no javascript.

Exemplo:

```
$dados = [1, 2, 3];

$json = json_encode($dados);

$callback = $_GET['callback'];

printf('%s(%s)', $callback, $json);
```

Requisição:

```
jsonp.php?callback=my_function
```

Resultado:

```
my_function([1, 2, 3]);
```

Porém, a minha preocupação é se o valor passado como callback é um valor de uma função javascript válida.

Isso é realmente algo que eu devo me preocupar?

Comment: Mas o objetivo do `JSONP` não é retornar o nome de uma função pré-definida na página requerente ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Com certeza! Muito embora quem esteja correndo maior risco é a página que usa seu serviço (afinal *você* poderia injetar código malicioso nela), existem ataques que se aproveitam do fato do servidor não sanitizar suas entradas. A wikipedia [lista alguns deles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#Security_concerns). Vou dar apenas um exemplo, que deve ser suficiente pra perceber a importância de validar aquilo que seu servidor envia ao usuário.

## *Reflected File Download*

A ideia por trás [desse ataque](https://www.trustwave.com/Resources/SpiderLabs-Blog/Reflected-File-Download---A-New-Web-Attack-Vector/) é explorar sites que refletem de volta conteúdo arbitrário enviado a eles. O *browser*, vendo o conteúdo malicioso chegar do site legítimo, age sobre esse conteúdo sem questionar. É um exemplo do [*confused deputy attack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confused_deputy_problem).

No caso do JSONP o que um atacante consegue fazer é limitado, mas eu encontrei [um exemplo](http://blog.davidvassallo.me/2014/11/02/practical-reflected-file-download-and-jsonp/) que utiliza esse protocolo. Vou tentar sumarizá-lo aqui (não tem como anonimizar - já que o artigo está publicamente disponível e facilmente recuperável - mas vou evitar citar o serviço real aqui porque não tenho certeza se essa vulnerabilidade já foi ou não consertada):

- O seu site possui uma API JSONP para obter uma informação qualquer:

  ```
  http://example.com/api/jsonp?callback=myCallback
  ```
- Ele não valida o nome da função, permitindo executar código arbitrário:

  ```
  http://example.com/api/jsonp?callback=alert%28document.cookie%29%3Bfoo{}
  ```

  Executa no *browser* do usuário:

  ```
  alert(document.cookie);
  foo{}( resposta do jsonp );
  ```

  Ok, os cookies do usuário foram acessados, mas até aí quem está com problemas é só o site que fez a requisição, não o seu...
- O HTML5 possui um atributo para o elemento `a` - `download` - que faz com que quando o usuário clicar no link em vez do *browser* o levar para uma página, um download é iniciado. Segundo [a documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#Attributes) ele suporta até mesmo URIs do tipo `blob:` e `data:`! (Nota: não sei as implicações disso na segurança, e de todo modo não é relevante pra esse caso)

  Suponha que um link desses seja criado apontando pra API JSONP do seu site:

  ```
  <a href="http://example.com/api/jsonp?callback=algo_malicioso" download="instalador.exe">Link legal!</a>
  ```

  Se seu site alegremente refletir esse conteúdo de volta, um download será iniciado no *browser* do usuário, reportado como **vindo do seu site**, mas o conteúdo do mesmo foi parcialmente fornecido pelo atacante (que pode dar um jeito de ignorar o que você postou de volta, segundo a sintaxe específica do arquivo que ele quer retornar).

Tudo o que o atacante precisa fazer então é convencer algumas pessoas (num processo de *phishing* por exemplo) a acessar esse link e abrir o arquivo retornado. Note que mesmo os usuários mais atentos vão olhar pra URL e constatar que de fato é um link pro *seu site*... E o *browser* em si também considerará isso ao aplicar suas políticas de segurança pra downloads.

## OK, validar é preciso, mas como?

Como o Marco Aurelio já comentou em [sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/87845/215), quanto mais validação você fizer mais restrita será a forma de usar seu serviço (o cliente quer `objetoGlobal.array[42].objeto.metodo`, mas você só aceita *callbacks* simples, ele é obrigado a criar uma nova função global). Entretanto, isso não deve ser um grande problema - basta o script definir a nova função global, com um nome aleatório e único, e removê-la ao final da execução. Uma validação simples como a *regex* sugerida me parece de bom tamanho.

Você poderia também "violar as regras do JSONP" de modo a tornar mais difícil explorar vulnerabilidades desse tipo. Em vez de retornar:

```
callback({ ... });
```

você poderia retornar:

```
;(function() { callback({ ... }); })();
```

e o resultado deveria ser o mesmo (e fica mais difícil - mas não impossível - agir num conteúdo que está *no meio* de uma expressão, não no seu início). **Não estou dizendo que é necessariamente uma boa ideia**, apenas levantando uma possibilidade...

No fim das contas, o ideal mesmo é evitar JSONP sempre que possível. Já avaliou a possibilidade de usar CORS? Permitir domínios arbitrários acessarem seu servidor é sempre um risco, e você teria que se planejar de acordo (ex.: não confiar somente nos cookies para determinar se um usuário está ou não logado), mas pelo menos nesse caso você estaria lidando apenas com **dados**, que são muito mais simples de gerenciar que **código**, além de não ficar amarrado a ecoar de volta algo recebido do cliente.

Comment: Troquei o "resolvido" pois acho que essa resposta tem mais detalhes :)

Comment: Valeu! É bom que assim mais pessoas ficarão cientes dessa possibilidade. Até há pouco eu também concordava com a outra resposta, mas segurança é assim mesmo: cada mudança na tecnologia muda também nossos pressupostos, e aquilo que antes era seguro de repente deixa de ser.

Answer (score 4):

Voce *pode* validar a função chamada, mas isso vai restringir o uso do seu serviço.

Um ataque poderia ocorrer como forma de injetar código em alguma página, onde o código de retorno do javascript(jsonp) seria executado. Mas o código naquela página já estaria comprometido por deixar executar qualquer coisa. O problema estaria na página e não no serviço.

Você poderia restringir o uso a apenas nomes. Algo como nessa regular expression:

```
^[A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*$
```

leia-se: nome deve iniciar com um caracter texto maiúsculo ou minúsculo, ou um underscore, seguido por multiplos caracteres texto ou numeros ou underscore.

Creio que outros caracteres poderiam ser adicionados sem muito problema, como o ponto, por exemplo.

Mas grande problema de segurança fica na aplicação que está usando o seu serviço, por permitir injeção de código na página ou ser uma página maliciosa. Mesmo que você filtre o seu serviço, poderão haver outros disponíveis para o ataque. Ou a página atacada poderá ter mais código com wrappers em forma de função válida.

Se o problema é a segurança dos dados, talvez você possa adicionar controle de acesso ao serviço e criptografia.

Comment: Embora você tenha aceitado essa resposta, peço por favor que dê uma olhada na [minha](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88181/215); **existe sim** um risco bem real em não se validar a entrada do usuário e ecoar de volta para o cliente. De todo modo, uma validação tal como sugerida aqui me parece uma boa ideia.